# Spring Boot JPA - Is it possible to batch insert with IDENTITY generator or equivelant?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I just recently found out about batch inserting in Spring Boot JPA 2.2.6 and Mysql 8.

To get batch insertions working I had to change the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;
```

to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;
```

With some additional properties:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 1000
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
```

Batch inserting seems to be working when I test with a single server instance. But I have just noticed that the id incrementing is not working correctly when there are two instances of the API.

What seems to be happening is:

1. POST to create an entity and persist it in the MySQL database. The request is received by instance 1. The entity gets the id of 1.
2. POST to create an entity and persist it in the MySQL database. The request is received by the instance 2 (Round Robin request routing). The following exception is thrown:

```
    Aug 10 20:47:00 ip-10-1-0-120.dev.dev.uk bash[25107]: 2020-08-10 20:47:00.408  INFO 25107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    Aug 10 20:47:00 ip-10-1-0-120.dev.dev.uk bash[25107]: 2020-08-10 20:47:00.410 ERROR 25107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'], SQL: insert into REMINDER (deleted, created, created_by, last_modified, last_modified_by, context, notification_type, reminder_date, user_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Aug 10 20:47:00 ip-10-1-0-120.dev.dev.uk bash[25107]: 2020-08-10 20:47:00.411  WARN 25107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
    Aug 10 20:47:00 ip-10-1-0-120.dev.dev.uk bash[25107]: 2020-08-10 20:47:00.412 ERROR 25107 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I prevent duplicate key exceptions being thrown when using multiple instances when I want to use batched inserting, but also ensure each new entity is always getting the next available incremented id across multiple instances?

Comment: you have to change it from `long` to `Long` because primatives cant be null but `Long` Can be. With your id set to null spring will automatically get the next id for it as long as you have it setup correctly in the database to increment the id.

Answer (score 0):

`GenerationType.IDENTITY` does not allow batch insertion. You can see this, for example, [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#GenerationTypeIDENTITY).

Indeed, this code will not work when using multiple instances. Because strategy `increment` using `IncrementGenerator` implementation. There you can see that the maximum ID value from database is cached. Therefore, if another instance of the application inserted a value, then the current instance will never know about it.

To solve your problem you can use

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
```

or you should change your database to PostgreSQL and then you must use `sequence` strategy.

If these options do not suit you, you can see the implementation of other strategies for generating an identifier in the `DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory`